# Ajaxplorer uploaded files have the wrong permissions

Tags: php, pydio

When I upload a file with Ajaxplorer 3.2.4 it always sets the file permissions of the uploaded file to 0600 and I can't access the uploaded files (like images) directly.

Is there a way to set the default file permissions for uploaded files to 0664?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to modify the file `(ajaxplorer_base_dir)/server/conf/conf.php`.

Look for the string `CHMOD_VALUE` and edit the associated value from `600` to `664`.